# what is under the hood for the "ga" function in R for continuous

Tags: r, optimization, genetic-algorithm

The "ga" function from the ["GA" library](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GA/GA.pdf) in R has several "type" options including "real-valued", and two optim-related flags.  This continuous-domain optimization applies a non-genetic approach as part of its function.

I can solve my problem using the ga, but I am having problems with other solvers.  The ga solves it, but it takes a very long time.

How can I find out what is really running in the back-end of "ga" so that I can get a solver that I knows works in order to get to it?

Is there an online example working through whatever tool is being used that shows how to set flags for my "fitness" function?

Comment: The way to know what a function in R is doing is to examine the source code. The various ways to find that information are catalogued extensively [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19226816/324364).

Comment: That is an excellent link.  thanks!